# Sending MouseListener data back to the game handler

Tags: java, program-entry-point, mouselistener

So my Java program has a Main class that creates and initializes the Game object.  The Game class contains the code that handles the procession of my program.  My Game class initializes my Display class.  My Display class initializes my DisplayPanel class.  My DisplayPanel class implements MouseListener.

My problem is that I want to send the MouseListener data back to the Game object on demand.  But I can't access my the game object properly from DisplayPanel because it is contained within the Main class and method.

I can't think of a proper way to work around this.  I'm sure this issue and issues like this are fairly common and would appreciate to know what the common and proper way to handle this issue and ones like this is.

I will post code if you really think it's necessary but I feel like I've explained everything you really need to know and it would be a waste of my time.

Comment: When you say "on demand", do you mean as a synchronous polling sort of thing, or as soon as the event is fired?

Comment: As soon as the method (mouseClicked, etc.) is called.  Like ideally I would like to send the data using a method call in mouseClicked() for example.

Comment: It sounds like the `DisplayPanel` doesn't need to know about the mouse input. In that case I'd recommend having a `MouseListener` reference in the `DisplayPanel` which can be set by its parent class, then providing your own `MouseListener` from within the Game class. If necessary, add the necessary methods to pass it from Game to Display to DisplayPanel.

Comment: So you're saying that Game should implement MouseListener?

Comment: It's not necessary to have any class implement it - in fact that's somewhat hacky, in my opinion. Instead do this:

    `MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() { 
        public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
             // do stuff..
        }
    }

    displayPanel.addMouseListener(listener);`

Comment: But if the MouseListener is initialized in Game how will I attach it to the DisplayPanel (It extends JPanel if you hadn't guessed that). And Im sorry if Im missing something obvious

Comment: You'll provide methods which allow you to pass the listener from the Game all the way down to the DisplayPanel, where you'll attach it.

Comment: So like a setMouseListener method? I see what you're saying now

Comment: Yup, exactly like that. In general, if a class doesn't need to know about something (e.g. mouse events), don't make it. Let it send that information away somewhere else painlessly.

Comment: So I ended up just making a MouseListener variable in Game that is initialized in the constructor and later on I just put "display.panel.addMouseListener(ml);" Probably not the best way but it works and it was painless! Thanks for the help, kept me from spending two hours thinking of this simple solution.  Do you mind adding an answer that directs to these comments so I can mark this as solved or however this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As established in the comments:

The easiest way of getting this to happen would be in the `Game` class, like so:

```
public class Game {
    private MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseListener() {
        public void onClick(MouseEvent e) {
            // application logic here
        }

        public Game() {
            DisplayPanel dp = new DisplayPanel();
            dp.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        }
    };
}
```

Then, you simply direct it to the `DisplayPanel` class through a series of method calls:

```
public class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {
    public void addMouseListener(MouseListener mouseListener) {
        this.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    }
}
```

(Note that in this case, since JPanel has an addMouseListener method, implementing your own is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 0):

**-** A quick fix will be making  `static` variable of appropriate **type** in `Game` class, which will hold the **data** of `MouseListener` send back from `DisplayPanel` class.

Comment: The Game class will need to be able to receive numerous coordinates though during it operating time and handle them when they occur.  Will this this be doable just using a static variable?

Comment: @Mirrorcrazy, at an instance there will be only 2 co-ordinates, so take 2 static variables holding the x-y locations, then take those values and put to the use, consume the locations as you get it or store it.

Comment: But how will Game know when to "consume" or store the variables?

Comment: @Mirrorcrazy it will be your logic in the Game class that will determine when to consume or store the variables

Comment: But something would need to tell it to "consume" the variables, it doesn't know when their altered